# IOS Swift - modal view error

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog

I'm facing a very weird bug in Swift.

I created a ViewController (A) embeded in a NavigationController.
On the top right I have BarButtonItem who has a segue set in the Storyboard in modal to another Viewcontroller(B).

In the main VC (A), I have multiple TextField who's delegate is the main VC.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    intervalTextField.delegate = self
    endTimeTextField.delegate = self
    ... 
}
```

When I run my app, and the new ViewController (B) (in the storyboard) is not bind with ViewController.swift (B). When I click de bar button (from A). It shows the modal (B) with no problem. When I bind (B) in de StoryBoard with the swift files for the modal viewController (B). Biiim...

I got this error :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

and the debugger point to the definition of the first TextField delegate in the main ViewController (A) with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.

I deleted (B) an created another ViewController (C) (Storyboard first), not binded with the code. It works. I create another ViewController.swift (C), I bind them. Same error happen when I put a modal segue between (A) and (C)

What could be the problem and why this error ? oO

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I added A, B, C for more understanding. And also the (A) controller works very well, my textFields are working fine, are declared, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to update your question explicitly saying which view controller is which. I'm a little confused with where exactly you're running into the error but basically this exception is thrown because your `UITextField` is `nil`. Make sure you've connected any `IBOutlet` to your view controller properly. Right-click the UITextField to see if it has the right connection. If it's connected properly you'll see a little black dot in your `IBOutlet` like so:

[image]

^

Hovering over and clicking the dot should take you to the proper `UITextField` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my post for more clarity. and the problem should not be there because all of the (A) Controller works fine.

Comment: In your question you wrote "the debugger point to the definition of the first TextField delegate in the main ViewController". Doesn't that mean your main view controller (A) does not work fine? In IB, if you right-click `intervalTextField`, does it show a referencing outlet?

Comment: That's the mystery... Everything works fine on the (A), I click on the BarButton to load (B). and we can see in the stacktrace that before pointing to the TextField's delegate declaration that we were in the viewDidLoad of (B). That's why I don't understant why the debugger point in the (A).

Comment: I recreated your error, but from the information you've given, the only thing I can deduct is that whatever textfield that is causing the error is not connected properly from Interface Builder to the proper IBOutlet in your code. Again, when you right-clicked the textfield in Interface Builder, does the name of the referencing outlet match the name in it's associated view controller and its been connected (shown by the little grey dot)?

Comment: My TextFields are binded. Here's screenshot http://258labs.be/others/projet-textfield-bind-1.png http://258labs.be/others/projet-textfield-bind-2.png

Comment: Unfortunately I would need to take a look at your code as I don't have the proper context for what's going on. Otherwise maybe someone with more experience would be able to help.

Comment: Actually, I opted to a Show (push) segue and everything works fine. But I want to understand why when it's in modal (the segue), it crashes and the debugger come bag to the (A) controller. Very mysterious ! Thanks anyway for your help ! ;)